# Finding data in Firebase

Tags: reference, exists, firebase

I'm trying to check if a username is used as in the example given in the Firebase docs:

---

```
function go() {
  var userId = prompt('Username?', 'Guest');
  checkIfUserExists(userId);
}

var USERS_LOCATION = 'https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users';

function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
  if (exists) {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' exists!');
  } else {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' does not exist!');
  }
}

// Tests to see if /users/<userId> has any data. 
function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
  var usersRef = new Firebase(USERS_LOCATION);
  usersRef.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
  });
}
```

---

But the data I'm referencing is in a layer of data that I'm having a problem referencing:

firebaseio.com/{userID}/primary/{username}

151 (userID)
  |
  |> primary 
           |
           |> username: username

I want to check the username field under the primary tree under a userID child... any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jim! I'm a bit confused by your structure. If my user ID is 151 and my name is "kato", then the data in the path would be `151/primary/kato/kato`? Or is `{username}` a misprint in your example?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what your data structure is; see my comment above. Making a couple assumptions about your data, that it looks something like this:

```
{151}/primary/username/{kato}
```

Where the parts in braces are the variable bits and the rest is a fixed key, then you just need to change your path as follows:

```
// in checkIfUserExists
usersRef.child(userId).child('primary/username').on('value', ...)
```

If you don't have the userID, then you could iterate all users and check the names:

```
usersRef.once('value', function(ss) {
    ss.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       var userID = childSnapshot.name();
       childSnapshot.ref().child('primary/username').once('value', function(ss) {
           var userName = ss.val();
           /* do something with name and ID here */
       });
    });
});
```

Alternately, if you suspect your user list is going to be ludicrously huge (many thousands), you may want to index usernames to ids in a separate path and avoid any iteration:

```
userList/{username}/{userID}
```

Which you could then use as follows:

```
 userListRef.child(username).once('value', function(ss) {
    var userID = ss.val();
    if( userID !== null ) {
        /* user exists and we have the name and id now */
    }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity -- I did mean {151}/primary/username/{kato}... In the solution you gave though, since I never named 151 as a userID and never supply a userID, how would it no to cycle through all the userIDs?

It's the usernames that I'm trying to compare not the userIDs?

Comment: Thanks it did help -- here's how it looks when the dust settled:  var userRef = new Firebase('https://j2000.firebaseio.com/users/');var usernameRef = userRef.on('child_added', function(userSnapshot) { var userData = userSnapshot.val();
if ( userData.primary.username === newusername ) { exists=newusername; userExistsCallback(exists); } else { exists = null; userExistsCallback(exists); }
 });
}

Comment: One of the difficulties with using `'child_added'`, which is intended more for a real-time listener than a find operation, is that if the entry isn't found, it will never complete (it just waits indefinitely for the right `child_added' event).